# How do I turn a dictionary into a string?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

```
params = {'fruit':'orange', 'color':'red', 'size':'5'}
```

How can I turn that into a string:

```
fruit=orange&color=red&size=5
```

Comment: Is this for creating URLs or for some other purpose? How do you want special characters inside the strings to be handled? Should they be escaped for use as URLs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
'&'.join('%s=%s' % (k,v) for k,v in params.items())
```

If you are building strings for a URL it would be better to use urllib as this will escape correctly for you too:

```
>>> params = { 'foo' : 'bar+baz', 'qux' : 'quux' }
>>> urllib.urlencode(params)
'qux=quux&foo=bar%2Bbaz'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are encoding url parameters, you can use [`urllib.urlencode`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) to accomplish this. For example:

```
import urllib
params = {'fruit':'orange', 'color':'red', 'size':'5'}
encoding = urllib.urlencode(params)
```

this will also run the dict through `urllib.quote_plus`.

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking about this?

```
>>> params = {'fruit':'orange', 'color':'red', 'size':'5'}
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.urlencode( params )
'color=red&fruit=orange&size=5'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a querystring, Python comes with batteries included:

```
 import urllib
 print(urllib.urlencode({'fruit':'orange', 'color':'red', 'size':'5'}))
```